# Detect when at the top of a ListView

Tags: react-native

I'm using a [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) component to display a simple list with section headers.

The `ListView` component has events for `onEndReached` but I could not find an `onBeginningReached` event.

How do you detect that a user has scrolled to the very top of the `ListView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such callback provided. Here is a workaround in React Native .. I assume ReactJS should have something similar

`<ListView onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)} ... />`

`handleScroll(event) {
 console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
}`

You can see that the value printed when scrolled on top will be negative. See if that works and help..

Comment: In React Native it does ... that is where I am using it ... just updated the original reply to say ListView instead of ScrollView ...

Comment: Yes, this is for react-native.  Thanks, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: thanks. when value of y has reached to 0 then we can find that first item is visible.